# Selenium Java-Object changes location dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ui-automation

[image]There are 3 categories of users: Authorized, Non-Authorized and Total Users. Users can be created through UI and by default the users will be displayed in the Non-Authorized section. There is a Toggle button available for users on each of the 3 page sections. When user clicks on the toggle button for a user from Non-Authorized section the user entry goes in the Authorized page.

Automation Requirement is to click on every toggle button of the user, check if all the buttons are clicked and then navigate to page users to check if all users are added.

The problem is that the when the toggle button is clicked of any user the top/bottom record HTML position gets replaced with the preceeding one.
eg: if the path of the 1st toggle button is //*[@id='xyz']/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUA7Q.png) and user clicks on this toggle button the next user records toggle buttons path now becomes same as above i.e//*[@id='xyz']/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUA7Q.png)

Below is the html code of the toggle switch:
`<span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 20px;"></span>`

I have tried to add Thread.sleep() after every toggle button click so that there is a delay and then my code can click on the next toggle switch using the same path but was wondering if there is a optimized way to handle this scenario.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Share html in text format

Comment: <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 20px;"></span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to click first toggle and wait until it disappears inside while loop with any toggle exists condition:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
while (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".bootstrap-switch-handle-off")).size() > 0) {
    WebElement toggle =
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".bootstrap-switch-handle-off")));
    toggle.click();
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(toggle));
    wait.until(d -> {
        try {
            return !toggle.isDisplayed();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ignored) {
           return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Code fails after clicking upon the first toggle on the line ```wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".bootstrap-switch-handle-off")))```;

Comment: ```org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.cssSelector: .bootstrap-switch-handle-off```

Comment: Try exactly code I shared. There's difference between `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(toggle));` and `invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".bootstrap-switch-handle-off"))); `.

Comment: Well there is no method called invisibilityOf in ExpectedConditions, is that a custom one ur talking about ?

Comment: Standart condition in `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;`.  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

Comment: There is visibilityOf(webelement ) available for ExpectedConditions but invisibilityOf does not exist .... sharing screenshot

Comment: Added the screenshot of the methods that are available in ExpectedConditions, as seen the invisibilityOf is not available

Comment: Try updated code. What Selenium version do you use?

Comment: 2.53.1 and unfortunately i couldn't update to the latest version as there are some other dependencies of the framework ... could you suggest any alternative for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199126/discussion-between-sers-and-automation-engr).